# Redis creating keys efficiently

Tags: database, optimization, redis, high-availability, nosql

I am trying to store some data in redis.

Consider following example.

A person has different cars owned in different years.

Currently I am storing keys like this -

```
cars:johndoe:1991:mercedes model s1 engine v1
cars:johndoe:1992:mercedes model s1 engine v1
cars:jane:1992:BMW model s2 engine v2
cars:foobar:1991:honda model s3 engine v3
```

Advantage of this is that - I can use wildcard with key to fetch different data.
e.g

```
1. all cars bought in 1991
keys cars:*:1991:*

2. all cars owned by johndoe
keys cars:johndoe:*
```

etc.

But as per redis documentation, `keys` command with wildcard is not efficient, as it searches all keys.
So I decided to use sets for this data. 
But to achieve same results like above, I need many different types sets e.g

```
1. sadd cars cars:johndoe:1991:mercedes cars:johndoe:1992:mercedes cars:jane:1992:BMW cars:foobar:1991:honda
2. sadd cars:johndoe cars:johndoe:1991:mercedes cars:johndoe:1992:mercedes
3. sadd cars:jane cars:jane:1992:BMW 
4. sadd cars:foobar cars:foobar:1991:honda
5. sadd cars:1991 cars cars:johndoe:1991:mercedes  cars:foobar:1991:honda
```

This way, I need to add & remove many keys for single operation.

Is this the only way ? Please let me know if there is any more efficient workaround for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For these kind of operations, I would use MongoDB.

Comment: @BhushanPatil thanks for comment. But I am also looking for good cache with less powerful machine.

Answer (score 0):

In the first method instead of using keys you can use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan)

You can write a simple lua script or even in your app logic you can iterate over the scan command with the cursor point and get all the keys matching the given pattern.

IMO if you have lot of criteria to be dealt then 1st option would be the best fit

1. You can avoid hitting multiple sadds
2. Retrieve based on any conditions

If you have less number of criteria the 2nd option would be the best fit

1. No need of iterating with scan command, you will have the keys to look up for ready.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using twisted, not sure, how it goes, will try for sure. Upvoted your answer but it might not getting displayed due to my low reputation.Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

These are, indeed, the only two approaches - not only for Redis but any database for that matter. It is the classic space-time tradeoff: either pay with RAM (i.e. store multiple indices [Sets]) to make the search fast or use CPU (i.e. do an ad-hoc scan).

Redis' philosophy is use space because our goal is maximizing performance. This means you want to store your data in the manner you're going to need it. Since in your case you're interested in reading the data using different dimensions, you need to index each of these dimensions appropriately. Redis' Sets are a good choice for that type of index, excluding the "make year" datum which could benefit from being indexed in a Sorted Set to facilitate range searches (over years, but only if needed).

Comment: Thanks for answer.